# Passing model from view to vontroller via Jquery ajax

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass Json data from the view to the controller but for some reason It is not wanting to work.  When I debug the controller, my model is showing as null and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Here's my Controller:

```
        public JsonResult UpdateVideoUrl(List<GetUrlData> model)
    {
        //var UpdateUrls = new AppServices.Video.UpdateAllVideo();
        //var loginVideoUrl = model.ToString();
        //dynamic update = UpdateUrls.Execute(model);
        return Json(model);
    }
```

My View:

```
    $('#btnUpdate').click(function (e) {
    //debugger;
    var model = {
        'Model.LoginFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#LoginEnVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.LoginFiles.SpanishVideoURL': $("#LoginEsVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.WelcomeFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#WelcomeEnVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.WelcomeFiles.SpanishVideoURL': $("#WelcomeEsVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.BenefitFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#BenefitEnVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.BenefitFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#BenefitEsVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.MyEnrollmentFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#MyEnrollmentEnVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.MyEnrollmentFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#MyEnrollmentEsVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.AdminSideFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#AdminSideEnVideoInput").val(),
        'Model.AdminSideFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#AdminSideEsVideoInput").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateVideoUrl", "ManageVideos")',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //async: true,
        success: function (model) {
            //Return the model
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown, errorThrown) {
            console.log("there was an error on post: " + " " + errorThrown + "." + "  Please see above if applicable");
        }
    });
});
```

And my Model:

```
    public class ApplicationVideoModel
{
    public List<GetUrlData> GetUrlData { get; set; }
}

public class GetUrlData
{
    public GetUrlData(string englishurl, string spanishurl)
    {
        EnglishVideoUrl = englishurl;
        SpanishVideoUrl = spanishurl;
    }
    public string EnglishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpanishVideoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model comes null because you convert **one object** and not **list of objects**.

If you change your parameter in your post method to:

```
public JsonResult UpdateVideoUrl(GetUrlData model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

then model won't be null.

If you need send List as parameter, then you have to stringify array of objects like this:

```
var model = [{
    'Model.LoginFiles.EnglishVideoURL': $("#LoginEnVideoInput").val(),
    next properties
            },
            {
    second object
            }]
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  Thanks.